# EntityFramework. Обновление данных в таблице связанных многие ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте!
Есть 2 таблицы связанные многие ко многим через промежуточную таблицу.

```
    public class Station
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<RailwayStation> RailwayStations { get; set; }                        
}


public class RailwayStation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Station> Stations { get; set; }               
}
```

Связь:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Station>()
       .HasMany(c => c.RailwayStations)
       .WithMany(p => p.Stations)
       .Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("RailwayStationsAllStations");

           m.MapLeftKey("StationId");
           m.MapRightKey("RailwayStationId");
       });
```

Создание записи (проходит успешно):

```
var stations = _unitOfWork.StationRepository.Get().OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToList();
_unitOfWork.RailwayStationRepository.Insert(new RailwayStation {Name = "Вокзал 2", AllStations = new List<Station>(stations.Skip(3))});
```

Промежуточная таблица RailwayStationsAllStations заполняется индексами верно.

Попытка обновления списка станций у таблицы RailwayStation

```
        var rs = _unitOfWork.RailwayStationRepository.GetById(1);  
        rs.Stations = new List<Station>(stations.Skip(1).ToList());
        rs.Name = "aaa";

        _unitOfWork.RailwayStationRepository.Update(rs);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
```

Происходит исключение

"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."

Я так понял не может найти соответствие по внешним ключам.
Если закоментировать

```
 rs.Stations = new List<Station>(stations.Skip(1).ToList());
```

то

```
 rs.Name = "aaa";
```

срабатывает.

UnitOfWork и GenericRepository

```
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly CisDbContext _context;
    private GenericRepository<Station> _stationRepository;
    private GenericRepository<RegulatorySchedule> _regulatoryScheduleRepository;
    private GenericRepository<OperativeSchedule> _operativeScheduleRepository;
    private GenericRepository<RailwayStation> _railwayStationRepository;


    public UnitOfWork(CisDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }



    public IRepository<Station> StationRepository => _stationRepository ?? (_stationRepository = new GenericRepository<Station>(_context));
    public IRepository<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleRepository => _regulatoryScheduleRepository ?? (_regulatoryScheduleRepository = new GenericRepository<RegulatorySchedule>(_context));
    public IRepository<OperativeSchedule> OperativeScheduleRepository => _operativeScheduleRepository ?? (_operativeScheduleRepository = new GenericRepository<OperativeSchedule>(_context));
    public IRepository<RailwayStation> RailwayStationRepository => _railwayStationRepository ?? (_railwayStationRepository = new GenericRepository<RailwayStation>(_context));



    public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}


    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    protected CisDbContext Context { get; }
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; }



    public GenericRepository(CisDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

    }



    public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }


    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await DbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }


    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }


    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Search(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Get();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split                        //управление ленивой загрузкой
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return orderBy?.Invoke(query) ?? query;
    }


    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }


    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }


    public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Прошу помощи, я новичок в EF.

Comment: Не хватает реализации `unitOfWork`.

Comment: Я думал в таблицах проблема где-то указать внешние ключи

Comment: Добавлю unitOfWork

Comment: //удаление прошло успешно тоже с удалением данных из промежуточной таблицы
var rs = _unitOfWork.RailwayStationRepository.GetById(2);  
_unitOfWork.RailwayStationRepository.Remove(rs);
await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();